# When and for what purposes should the const keyword be used in C for variables?

Tags: c, readability, patterns-and-practices, const

While getting [my code reviewed here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28285/binary-search-in-c-optimization) the issue of using the `const` keyword came up. I understand that it is used for implementing read-only behaviour on variables.

I am confused about what are the various situations when it can be useful.

- Should it be used for the sake of clarity in function prototypes?
- Should it be used as a security measure during code development?
- Should it be used in the scope of various functions for declaring run-time constants?
- Should it be used at all?

These question are just examples of the confusion that I am facing. The general confusion is

- When should be the `const` keyword used in C programming?
- What are the various types of benefits that can be gained by using this keyword in C?
- Are there any cons of using `const` keyword?

---

It has been pointed that this question may be too broad due to all these questions in the detail of my question. I just wanted to clarify that these questions are just to clarify the confusion regarding the main question.

> When and for what purposes should the const keyword be used in C for variables?

It can also be rephrased as

> The proper use of `const` keyword in C` with the pros and cons of the same.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

When reviewing code, I apply the following rules:

- Always use `const` for function parameters passed by reference where the
  function does not modify (or free) the data pointed to.

  ```
  int find(const int *data, size_t size, int value);
  ```
- Always use `const` for constants that might otherwise be defined using a #define or an enum.  The compiler can locate the data in read-only memory (ROM) as a result (although the linker is often a better tool for this purpose in embedded systems).

  ```
  const double PI = 3.14;
  ```
- Never use const in a function **prototype** for a parameter passed by
  **value**.  It has no meaning and is hence just 'noise'.

  ```
  // don't add const to 'value' or 'size'
  int find(const int *data, size_t size, int value);
  ```
- Where appropriate, use `const volatile` on locations that cannot be changed by the program but might still change.  Hardware registers are the typical use case here, for example a status register that reflects a device state:

  ```
  const volatile int32_t *DEVICE_STATUS =  (int32_t*) 0x100;
  ```

---

Other uses are optional.  For example, the parameters to a function within the function **implementation** can be marked as const.

```
// 'value' and 'size can be marked as const here
int find(const int *data, const size_t size, const int value)  
{
     ... etc
```

or function return values or calculations that are obtained and then never change:

```
char *repeat_str(const char *str, size_t n) 
{
    const size_t len = strlen(str);
    const size_t buf_size = 1 + (len * n);
    char *buf = malloc(buf_size);
    ...
```

These uses of `const` just indicate that you will not change the variable; they don't change how or where the variable is stored. The compiler can of course work out that a variable is not changed, but by adding `const` you allow it to enforce that.  This can help the reader and add some safety (although if your functions are big or
complicated enough that this makes a great difference, you arguably have other
problems). *Edit - eg. a 200-line densely coded function with nested loops and many long
or similar variable names, knowing that certain variables never change might
ease understaning significantly.  Such functions have been badly designed or
maintened.*

---

Problems with `const`.  You will probably hear the term "const poisoning".
This occurs when adding `const` to a function parameter causes 'constness' to
propagate.

*Edit - const poisoning: for example in the function:*

```
int function_a(char * str, int n)
{
    ...
    function_b(str);
    ...
}
```

*if we change `str` to `const`, we must then ensure that `fuction_b` also takes
a `const`.  And so on if `function_b` passes the `str` on to `function_c`,
etc.  As you can imagine this could be painful if it propagates into many
separate files/modules.  If it propagates into a function that cannot be
changed (eg a system library), then a cast becomes necessary.  So sprinkling
`const` around in existing code is perhaps asking for trouble.  In new code
though, it is best to `const` qualify consistently where appropriate.*

The more insidious problem of `const` is that it was not in the original
language. As an add-on it doesn't quite fit.  For a start it has two meanings
(as in the rules above, meaning "I'm not going to change this" and "this cannot be modified").  But more than that, it can be dangerous. For example, compile and
run this code and (depending upon the compiler/options) it may well crash when
run:

```
const char str[] = "hello world\n";
char *s = strchr(str, '\n');
*s = '\0';
```

`strchr` returns a `char*` not a `const char*`.  As its call parameter is
`const` it must **cast** the call parameter to `char*`.  And in this case that
casts away the real read-only storage property. *Edit: - this applies generally to vars in read-only memory. By 'ROM', I mean not just physical ROM but any memory that is write-protected, as happens to the code section of programs run on a typical OS.*

Many standard library functions behave in the same way, so beware: when you
have **real** constants (ie. stored in ROM) you must be very careful not to
lose their constness.

Comment: It doesn't really have two meanings. It just means, as you say, "**I'm** not going to change this." For example, it's perfectly valid to have a `const volatile` variable.

Comment: That is true of function parameters but for constants at file scope, for example, a `const` variable really is read-only: `const` says "This **cannot** be modified". A `const volatile` on the other hand says "This **cannot** be modified, but it might change".  I'll add a mention of volatiles to my answer.

Comment: I don't disagree with your comment, just with the idea that it's an instruction to the compiler to put it in ROM. That implies some sort of runtime guard against undefined behaviour (ie. modifying a const through somehow), which can lead to misunderstandings like "why can I change this `const` variable through a non-`const` pointer" (a common question on SO and every other C forum!). Overall I like this answer though :)

Comment: You are right, "Put this in ROM" is inaccurate (although succinct :-) - I'll change it to "This cannot be modified", which is more accurate.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: This is a great overview. I like to phrase it that `const` declares both read-only *data* and read-only *views* of data—the difference being “this cannot be modified” versus “you cannot modify this”.

Comment: "although if your functions are big or complicated enough that this makes a great difference, you arguably have other problems" - does that mean that the functions aren't properly designed or something else? About losing `const`ness does that take place for ROMs only or it can happen generally? Also can you elaborate about `const`ness propagation? I haven't heard anything you said after the horizontal ruler before this

Comment: Updated with some more comments - look for 'Edit'

Comment: The solution with `strchr()` would have been to have two functions. I don't know why they did it that way; it indeeds eliminates the benefits of `const`. In C++ you would have two functions for that (one that accepts `char *` and returns `char *`, and the other that accepts `const char *` and returns `const char *`). So in C, without name mangling, having the corresponding `strchr()` and `strchr_c()`, for example, would be safer.

Answer (score 16):

Generally in any programming language its recommended to use `const` or the equivalent modifier since

- It can clarify to the caller that what they passed in is not going to change
- Potential speed improvements since the compiler knows for certain it can omit certain things that are only relevant if the parameter can change
- Protection from yourself accidentally changing the value

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's basically the TheLQ's answer.

Is a security measure for the programmer so you don't modify a variable, and to not call functions that may modify them. In an array or structure the const specifier indicates that the values of their contents won't be modified, and even the compiler will not allow you to do so. You still can easily change the value of the variable with just a cast however.

In what I have usually see, it's mostly used to add constant values in code, and to indicate that the array or structure won't be modified if you call a particular function. This last part is important, because when you call a function that WILL modify your array or structure, you may want to keep the original version, so you create a copy of the variable and then pass it to function. If that is not the case, you don't require the copy, obviously, so for example you can change,

```
int foo(Structure s);
```

to

```
int foo(const Structure * s);
```

and not getting the copy overhead.

Just to add, note that C has particular rules with the const specifier. For example,

```
int b = 1;
const int * a = &b;
```

is not the same as

```
int b = 1;
int * const a = &b;
```

The first code won't allow you to modify value points by `a`. `* a = 3;` will error out.
In the second case, the pointer is constant but its contents is not, so the compiler will allow you to say `* a = 3;` without a compiler error, but you can't make `a` to be a reference to another thing.